# Getting java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available and BindException using Jsoup while connecting to url using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, jsoup, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying to do parser for a website, and because there's a lot of content, I used Kotlin coroutines to make parsing asynchronous, but I've ran into a problem where I constantly get 
 `java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[na:na]` and `Suppressed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: no further information at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]`
I use the function below to get a document

```kotlin
fun connect(url: String): Document {
        return try {
            Jsoup.connect(url).newRequest().get()
        } catch (_: SocketTimeoutException) {
            println("RETRYING $url")
            connect(url)
        }
    }
```

and

```kotlin
runBlocking { 
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val updated: ArrayList<Deferred<List<Book>>> = arrayListOf()

                    for (booklist in booklists) {
                        updated.add(async {
                            booklist.forEach { book -> book.sections = ru.parseBook(book) }

                            return@async booklist
                        })
                    }
                    updated.awaitAll().forEach { u -> bookRepository.saveAll(u) }
                }
            }
```

to run parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out via HttpClient which is being created for every Coroutine:

```
for (bookList in chunked) {
            updated.add(async {
                val client = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
                bookList.forEach { book -> book.sections = engine.parseBook(book, client) }

                return@async bookList
            })
        }
```

and passed as a variable into a function

```
val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI(url)).GET().build()
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val send = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                val doc = Jsoup.parse(send.body())
}
```